# How to generate a treeview in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

1. How to generate a tree view in asp.net?
2. In my asp.net project i need a tree view like structure, the format given below
   [alt text http://dev1.ispg.in/dg/untitled.bmp](http://dev1.ispg.in/dg/untitled.bmp)

Comment: 400kb picture is not the best idea..

Comment: please expand Govt Girls Home Node :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET does have a [`TreeView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28VS.80%29.aspx) that you can use to display a Treeview very similar to the one you show.

If you require the `Checkboxes` on each and every Treeview node, but sure to set the `ShowCheckBoxes` attribute to the appropriate setting  (i.e. `ShowCheckBoxes="All"`>

Regarding the nodes themselves, you can bind the `TreeView` to a `DataSource` which can either be an [ASP.NET `SiteMap` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx) or an XML Document.  Alternatively, you can programmatically add the nodes yourself in code like so:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
tn.Value = "Cities";
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
tn.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Cochin 1"));
[etc. etc.]
```

Some other useful links are:

[Using the TreeView Control and a DataList to Create an Online Image Gallery](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128065816/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/083006-1.aspx)
[ASP.NET Treeview Quickstart Tutorial](http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

use the asp.net treeview , have a look [here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx) everything is explained